# Putting csv file data into a level 2 array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I have been researching fgetcsv() and have the following working code:

```
$file = fopen($pathToCsv,"r");
$data = array();

while(! feof($file))
  {
      array_push($data, fgetcsv($file));
  }

fclose($file);
```

However, when I try to adapt this to dynamically accept an unknown number of csv files stored into an array, things cease to work:

```
$year = $_POST['year'];
$m = "maths".$year;
$sheets = $$m; //an array containing between 5 an 8 paths to csv and other info
$data = array();

function ArrayFromCsv($file, $i) {
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        array_push($data[$i], fgetcsv($file)); //line 15
    } 
    fclose($file);
}



for ($i = 0; $i < count($$m); $i++){
    array_push($data, array());
    $x = fopen($sheets[$i]['csv'],'r');
    ArrayFromCsv($x, $i);
}
```

I get: `Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in ... on line 15`

I'm not how to research this further. Is there a better way or obvious mistake? I've tried a number of methods.

Comment: `$data` is undefined in the scope of your `ArrayFromCsv` function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php can help you research this further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have access to the global $data variable inside of the function ArrayFromCsv. You either need to use "global $data" inside the function, `which is bad, so DON'T`
Or you could create a temporary array inside the function, which you return when the function ends and put the returned value from the function into `$data[$i]`. Also you should not open a file outside of a function and close it inside of a function. That could lead to undefined behaviour someday when your code gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

```
function ArrayFromCsv($file, $i) use (&$data) {
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        array_push($data[$i], fgetcsv($file)); //line 15
    } 
    fclose($file);
}
```